# What is the best way to minify CSS and JavaScript on an ASP.NET server?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, css, minify

I've got CSS and JavaScript on an ASP.NET server running .NET 4 with C#. How can I send minified CSS and JavaScript response to client?

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, looks more like a tag cloud.

Comment: Webforms or u work with MVC4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use **Microsoft Ajax Minifier**
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Download.ashx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a minifier, there are many online minify sites available you can use like [JSCompress](http://jscompress.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Closure-tool](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home). It also has a [RESTful api](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_api) which can be used easily.

Answer (score 0):

We use http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher it's really easy and good to use. You can simply choose debug or production mode in your configuration file.